# Change domain and url at once

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to proxy and change url at the same time.

I'm basically trying to accomplish the following

from
http://domain.com/8251363/6384
to
http://domain.co.uk/8251363/code/6384

I have been trying things like

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)(.*) /%1/code/%2
```

but no luck yet, any ideas

Comment: I have finally figured out the following rule, based on input so far RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]*) http://domain.co.uk/$1/code/$2 [P]  but hoe can I limit the rule to only two folder digits path ?

Answer (score 1):

[It seems that](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regex) the syntax to read a captured group of a rewrite rule is `$1`, not `%1`.

That is to say: `RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)(.*) /$1/code/$2`

But this will transform `/8251363/6384` to `/8251363/code//6384`.

So use: `RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/(.*) /$1/code/$2`

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out using http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ but the rule does not seem to work ?